# get value from xml using Xelement

Tags: xml, linq

I am trying to get the value of the attribute "Id" inside the entity element from the class with the name of "ECMInstruction" but nothing is returned.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Root>
      <Class Name="ECMInstruction" Style="Top">
        <Entity Id="1" Name="DocumentInformation" />
      </Class>
      <Class Name="dfgfggfdg" Style="Top">
        <Entity Id="1" Name="dfgfgfdgd" />
      </Class>
    </Root>

  private void dcLisT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       String curItem = dcList.SelectedItem.ToString();

       IEnumerable<String> lList =
         from el in doc.Descendants("Entity")
         where el.ElementsBeforeSelf("Class") && Attribute("Name").Value == curItem
         select (String)el.Attribute("Id").Value;

       EntityList.Items.AddRange(lList.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: It looks to me like that wouldn't even compile, given that `el.ElementsBeforeSelf("Class")` isn't a `bool` expression, and you're calling `Attribute` without specifying a target. Please show a short but *complete* program (ideally just a short console app) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
IEnumerable<String> lList = from el in doc.Descendants("Class")
                            where el.Attribute("Name").Value == curItem
                            select el.Element("Entity").Attribute("Id").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work :

```
        var lList = from a in xd.Descendants("Root").Elements("Class")
                    where a.Attribute("Name").Value == curItem
                    select a.Element("Entity").Attribute("Id").Value;
```